# Use of ‘und’ in Nebensatz

Tags: grammar, word-order, subordinate-clause

Which sentence is correct? Which is the word order if we have two subordinate clauses that are connected with *und*? I know that after *und* there is no change in place like in a subordinate clause but I don’t know what happens if the second part is a subordinate clause?

> Man muss auch anmerken, dass Eltern ihren Kindern Beispiel geben und Alkohol in Moderation trinken sollten.

or

> Man muss auch anmerken, dass Eltern ihren Kindern Beispiel geben und sollten Alkohol in Moderation trinken.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is not *if there is an ‘und’ keep the word order unchanged*. Rather, the rule is *put the verb at the end of a subordinate clause and in second position in main clauses*. The thing about *und* and *oder* is that they cannot only connect two (otherwise unconnected) main clauses, but can also do that with subordinate clauses.

> Ich habe gesagt, dass du mir ein Glas Wein geben sollst **und dass** du nicht so viel trinken sollst.

Would be a version of the sentence that includes every dropable fragment. It’s clear to see from the additional *dass* that we are dealing with two subordinate clauses, hence the word order. Now let’s start dropping:

> Ich habe gesagt, dass du mir ein Glas Wein geben sollst **und** du nicht so viel trinken sollst.

As you see, we can leave out the *dass* without any harm. Still subordinate clauses.

> Ich habe gesagt, dass du mir ein Glas Wein geben sollst **und** nicht so viel trinken sollst.
>
> Ich habe gesagt, dass du mir ein Glas Wein geben **und** nicht so viel trinken sollst.

As you see the word order is not changed during the dropping; we are still dealing with two subordinate clauses. The same works with *oder*, by the way:

> Ich denke, dass du jetzt eine neue Flasche Wein aufmachst **oder** uns gleich rauswerfen wirst.

As texNewbie already said, the word choice in your sentence is also improvable. I suggest the following:

> Man muss auch anmerken, dass Eltern ihren Kindern ein Vorbild sein und Alkohol nur in Maßen trinken sollten.

(Don’t write that in Switzerland, though, lest it becomes *in Massen* ;).)

Comment: I'm not fond of dropping "sollen" here. It doesn't sound well.

Answer (score 1):

It is the first one. *Sollten* relates to both of the subordinate clauses, so it has to stand at the end.

But nevertheless it is not correctly formulated. You can't say “Eltern ihren Kindern Beispiel geben sollten”, you have to say something like:

> Man muss auch anmerken, dass Eltern ihren Kindern ein Vorbild sein und Alkohol nur gemäßigt konsumieren/trinken sollten.

You don’t use the word to drink in “Moderation”. The word is mostly just used as verb. To do something “moderat”. But also there it is used very rare.

Comment: Yep, "Moderation" makes me more think of a host presenting a TV-show...